# Is there really such a thing as a skeleton key?

Tags: ignition, key, locks, ignition-key

I've worked in the motorcycle industry for a while. I've heard ridiculous claims of something called a "skeleton key" which could turn any ignition to "on".

Does something like this really exist? Is it purely for dealership purposes?

Are there make specific skeleton keys?

Skeleton keys for automobiles or skeleton keys depending on the style ignition?

Comment: There used to be such things for cars, but not a *universal* key. They used to only make so many different keys (something along the lines of 16 different cuts is what I remember). You could go out to a parking lot and put your key in and have a pretty good probability it would start a car. These days I can almost assure you there isn't such a thing. Could you imagine the liability a manufacturer would have if one of those keys got out to the public? I just don't think it would happen. This is all speculation though, thus the comment.

Comment: A modern car key contains an RFID chip so that, even if you can physically turn the ignition barren to "ON", without the chip the engine won't start and run.

Comment: @SteveMatthews I've also heard about those "chipped" keys. But I thought those were more common on luxury cars such as Mercedes, BMW, maybe Lexus, and so on.

Comment: @gh0st - [Check this listing](http://transponderkey.com/) for which cars use chipped keys. The list is very extensive.

Comment: I am under the impression physical keys are receiving less and less attention from builders, relying more on electronics. The last few car keys I have used were models that cannot have had more than a few thousand different possible combinations, if that.

Comment: just speculation but you may be thinking of a "shaved key". Some older models  of certain car brands  Honda and Nissan  come to mind used very fine cut keys. Meaning they had many small undulations (high and low spots) on the keys. As the lock cylinders wore, along with the key any key that was very worn would turn the cylinder providing it was the correct blank. As @Steve Mathews has stated that issue has been negated by keys with chips.

Comment: @ALANWARD - Taking it a step further, there are a lot of cars out there now which don't even use a conventional key, but rely on the key fob being close enough, then you push a button to start. Or, you just insert the end of the fob into the mechanism and turn to start. Either way, you are not relying on the cut of a key to get the engine started. There was a funny scene on Top Gear where Jeremy had one such car. One of the other two went out to the car, started it with the push button, and parked it in the street without him knowing. Made for entertaining TV!

Comment: @Paulster2 An acquaintance of mine had that type of keyless entry system on a Renault, but soon lost the fob down a storm drain. She was not amused by the cost to replace it.

Comment: Okay, would one of you goofballs please turn one or more of these comments into an answer?!